# Turning two one dimensional arrays into a 2 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, format

I want to write a code where it combines `a, b, c` and `unix_a, unix_b, unix_c` together into a multi dimensional array. `Long` would just turn into `1` and `Short` would turn into `0`s. The zeroes and ones would occupy the first column and the second column would just be the the `unix_` values just like: `[[1 1624580882]]`. How would I be able to get my `Expected Output`

```
import numpy as np 

a=np.array(["Short","Long","Short","Long","Short","Long"])
b=np.array(["Long","Long","Long","Long"])
c=np.array(["Short","Long","Short","Long","Short","Long"])

unix_a=np.array([1624580882,1624584458,1624589467,1624592213,1624595336,1624596349])
unix_b=np.array([1624580882,1624584458,1624595336,1624596349])
unix_c=np.array([1624580882,1624584464,1624589495,1624592238,1624595350,1624596380])
```

Expected Output:

```
[[0 1624580882], [1 1624584458], [0 1624589467], [1 1624592213], [0 1624595336], [1 1624596349]]

[[1 1624580882], [1 1624584458], [1 1624595336], [1 1624596349]]

[[0 1624580882], [1 1624584464], [0 1624589495], [1 1624592238], [0 1624595350], [1 1624596380]]
```

Comment: Have you tried a list comprehension with zip on each pair of arrays (ists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.c_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html):

```
np.c_[a=='Long',unix_a]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a list, you can use a list comprehension:

```
[(0 if a=="Short" else 1, b) for a,b in zip(a,unix_a)]
```

output:

```
[(0, 1624580882),
 (1, 1624584458),
 (0, 1624589467),
 (1, 1624592213),
 (0, 1624595336),
 (1, 1624596349)]
```

If you want a 2D numpy array:

```
np.array([(a=="Long").astype(int), unix_a]).T
```

output:

```
array([[         0, 1624580882],
       [         1, 1624584458],
       [         0, 1624589467],
       [         1, 1624592213],
       [         0, 1624595336],
       [         1, 1624596349]])
```

To convert all:

```
out_a, out_b, out_c = [np.array([(x[0]=="Long").astype(int), x[1]]).T
                       for x in [(a, unix_a), (b, unix_b), (c, unix_c)]]
```